# underscores word wrap function removes escape characters

Tags: javascript, underscore.string.js

consider the following string:

```
hello \\c[12]there\\c[0]
```

When passed to the [`wrap`](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#wrapstr-options--string)  it translates the string to:

```
hello
\c[12]there\c[0]
```

How ever I want it to return:

```
hello
\\c[12]there\\c[0]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you do `wrap('hello \\c[12]there\\c[0]'.replace(/\\/g, '\\'), {width: 7})`?

Comment: Noting that `hello \\c[12]there\\c[0]` will be converted to `\c[12]there\c[0]` by the javascript compiler/parser. `wrap` is unlikely to have anything to do with it. To code a string with two backslashes, escape both: `\\\\c[12]there\\\\c[0]`